# If the convolution of two functions f*g is equal g, f is even with compact support and g is bounded, then g is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $f$ is even continuous function with compact support such that $\int f(t)dt=1 $, $g$ is bounded continuous function and convolution (f*g)(x)=g(x). How to prove that if $g$ has global minimum then $g$ is constant. I thought about Convolution Theorem but it seems it doesn't work in this case. May be without restriction that $g$ has global minimum there is a way to prove that $g$ is linear.

Comment: So $g$ is continous - $f$ not?

Comment: sorry, f is continuous too

Comment: What the convolution theorem tells us here is that wherever the Fouriere transform of $g$ is nonzero and finite, the Fourier transform of $f$ must equal $1$. This seems to almost imply the transform of $f$ is constant over an open st, but actually the integral for the fourier transform of $g$ need not converge anywhere